# is it necessary to install maven in linux environment even though i am using eclipse juno version which already supports maven bydefault?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse juno version(RCP and RAP) in linux environment. Eclipse juno already has maven so, i think there is no need to install any m2e plugin. I want to use maven for Eclipse plug-in development. Please confirm me is it mandatory to install maven in this linux environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes

### Long Answer

Yes, you will want to run it from the command line. You will want to be able to update to the latest version, which Eclipse isn't running. You will want to be able to point other applications like Jenkins at `M2_HOME`, lots of other reasons as well.